# need understanding on guest-metrics in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-metrics

I am collecting metrics from Monitoring in google cloud through rest-api. In the api documentation from https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp I am seeing lot of metrics beginning with **guest** like

```
guest/cpu/usage_time 
guest/disk/bytes_used 
guest/disk/io_time
```

I am seeing the same kind of metrics beginnging with **instance** like

```
instance/cpu/usage_time
instance/disk/max_read_bytes_count
```

I have searched the documentation, but I am not getting clear idea of what is the difference between guest and instance metrics. Which metrics is preferred? Can anyone give suggestion? Thanks

Comment: On which metrics do you need clarification? What do you want to observe? According with your use case, the metrics to use will be different!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guest/... is used to monitor the [system health](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/monitoring#viewing_the_collected_metrics) of [COS instances](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance).

While for the instance/... it is targeted at regular GCE VM instances metrics not COS instance type.

Comment: thanks  this information is very useful to me does it mean that all api calls starting with guest are all related to COS (container optimized instances like kubernetes and not normally created instances